# Memory Usage of UIButton with Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, memory-management, uibutton

My app presents a scrolling list of buttons with image icons. I've found that even though the .png icon files are only 2 kb, their uncompressed versions are about 150 kb and the combined total of all the buttons is using too much device memory.

Originally each button was created within an instance of an object, so the code basically worked like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<buttonsCount; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

When I realized how much memory the images were using, I moved the image creation outside of the object and let all the objects use the same image. So now the code basically works like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon"];

for (int i=0; i<buttonsCount; i++) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

However, the memory usage is the same. Apparently UIButton is making its own copy of the image data. Is there any way to "share" the image data among many buttons?

When I run the app in Instruments using the Allocations tool, "VM: CG raster data" is the item that gets too large.

The only alternate solutions I can think of would be loading and unloading the buttons as needed while scrolling, but I'm afraid that would hurt the scrolling performance; or simply reducing the pixel size of the images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach similar to UITableView (or maybe use a UITableView directly). It only creates views (cells) for the items that are on screen, and then recycles these cells as they move offscreen. This means those views are not recreated all the time, they are just updated with the correct data just before they move on screen.